# How can I find the standard deviation in categorical distribution

Tags: categorical-data, standard-deviation, sample

How can I find the standard deviation in categorical distribution, where the elements have non-numerical attributes (e.g. colors)?

For example, I have a bag of marbles with $n$ colors. There's an infinite number of marbles in the bag, and are biased towards a certain color with a probability of $\frac{x}n, x>1$. From the bag, I pick $m$ marbles and get the probability distribution with respect to their colors.

From this distribution, by picking $q$ colors with the highest probabilities, I want to convince others with a confidence interval $k$% (e.g. 95%), that one of the colors I chose is the one that the marbles are biased towards.

In this scenario, what are some of the analysis techniques that can be used to find $q$, given $x,n,k,$ and $m$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no standard deviation of a categorical variable - it makes no sense, just as the mean makes no sense.  E.g. in your example, what is the "average color"?

But there are ways to estimate the error of a binomial or multinomial proportion. It isn't clear which you want, since your title seems to ask for the latter while your text seems to ask for the former. Even for the binomial proportion, it's trickier than many people think.

The classic formula for a 95% CI for a binomial proportion is

$CI=\hat{p} \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$

but this may not be best. See e.g [Brown, Cai & DasGupta](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-16/issue-2/Interval-Estimation-for-a-Binomial-Proportion/10.1214/ss/1009213286.full)

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks so much for your guidance in this matter. I think multinomial proportion is what I was looking for (many discrete choices with different probabilities). I found a recent journal article related to finding the exact confidence coefficients for multinomial proportion [here](http://www.stat.nctu.edu.tw/~hwang/16_JMVA2008.pdf). I think this would be the one to use.

Comment: Note that "exact" confidence intervals are not very accurate (see Agresti's work).  I don't know of a method for simultaneous confidence intervals, but for individual intervals Wilson's confidence interval is more accurate than "exact" methods.  It can be computed in R with the `Hmisc` package's `binconf` function.

Comment: Indeed. Agresti & Coull is an excellent entry into this literature.