# Is this a meaningful method to determine spread around mean?

Tags: standard-deviation, ordinal-data, methodology

I have student ratings of 123 schools across the US. They represent 100% of this type of school across the US.

The ratings are on the scale Poor, Fair, Good, and Superb, and I have the number and percentage of students giving each rating at each school.

Since this is ordinal data, I am not comfortable calculating a mean score on the rating scale for each school, and therefore I am not able to get a standard deviation to indicate spread around such a mean.

Would the following make sense / provide meaningful information?

Students infrequently rate their school as Poor, so I could determine when a school deviates from other schools because that school has, relatively speaking, a substantially higher percentage of students rating it as Poor.

I could use the percentage of Poor ratings for each school to calculate an average percentage of Poor ratings across the 123 schools, and then calculate a standard deviation based on that. In theory, that should tell me how much schools vary in their percent of Poor ratings.

But is that a legitimate, defensible calculation of a standard deviation that provides meaningful information about spread? Or would a different approach make more sense / be more defensible?

Comment: Like you said [using std dev for ordinal data does not make sense](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/51248/168982). I think showing the ratings at each quartile may make more sense. Currently, it feels like you are putting your own understanding of the situation to define the metric.

Comment: An alternative: for each school, calculate the percent of students who give a positive rating (f+g+s). [Obviously 100%- poor %). Rank all schools based on this measure and report each school's percentile ranking. This is not a spread measure but seems worth doing.

Comment: Thank you both.